# cell as an input argument for normxcorr2

Tags: matlab, cells

I want to calculate normalized cross correlation for an image with a lot of templates(31 templates). When I define templates as a cell and i compile :

```
parfor ii =1 :100
   T {ii,:}=normxcorr2(template{:} ,image{ii});
end
```

It returns an error, because the inputs of normxcorr2 can't be cells (only matrixs). I can of course use a for loop like :

```
parfor ii =1 :100
for j= 25:55
  % T {ii,j}=normxcorr2(template{j} ,image{ii});
end
end
```

However it makes more time (because of the nested loop).

My question is if there is a solution in order to not use a nested loop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe rearanging your templates in a cell array and then apply the `normxcorr2` as a `cellfun` can help you:

```
% generate random image and templates
image = rand(100);
% templates of 5X5
templates = rand(5,5,31);
% convert templates into cell array
templates = squeeze(mat2cell(templates,size(templates,1),...
    size(templates,2),ones(1,size(templates,3))));
% apply cellfun
T = cellfun(@(t) normxcorr2(t ,image),templates,'UniformOutput',0);
```

note that if your templates are not given in a cell array and template's sizes are not equal (here 5X5), then you will need to create the `templates` cell array in a different way (still simple though).